# Motto without sounding formal

Tags: translation, formal

I want to make a motto for myself in korean that goes like

> Remember your goal

I used Naver's website to translate the phrase above.

> 목표를 기억하세요.

I know that 요 indicates a polite voice. But I want my motto to be a personal mantra. Being **polite** is kind of odd.

So I thought, maybe I can omit 요 without the risk of changing the meaning of the sentence, since I learned that the use of 요 is dependent to the main phrase.

> 목표를 기억하세.

Does the phrase above sounds natural? Or is there a better way to say **Remember you goal**? Or is there any existing *motto* that has the meaning of remembering one's goal so as to motivate someone to achieve their goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

목표를 기억하세 sounds oddly funny, haha. But excellent try. You're right, ~하세 or ~함세 means let's go do something, but it's typically reserved for colloquial speech among the elderly especially from the southwestern provinces. It's an anachronism from the early to mid twentieth century, so the millennials when they are older will never say ~하세 or ~함세.

~하자 is what you're looking for, **목표를 기억하자**. If you want to say let's not forget the goal then it's **목표를 잊지말자**. A similar way of saying this would be **초심을 잊지말자**, which roughly translates to let's not forget how it all began.

If you want to actually achieve the goal and not just remember it:

**목표를 꼭 이루자/이룰 것이다/이루고 말테다!** 이루다 means achieve. You can also use 달성하다(달성하자/달성할 것이다/달성하고 말테다) or 도달하다(도달하자/도달할 것이다/도달하고 말테다) in lieu of 이루다.

Personally, I like the following:

**목표를 향해 전진하자!** Let's stride/march toward the goal.